# How can I get the result of a dialog before continuing in android

Tags: android, dialog

In the onCreate method of my activity, I called a method I made called getLocProvider().  It is supposed to return a location provider to me.  I made that method show an alert dialog, here is my code:

```
private void getLocProvider(){
    ArrayList<String> providers = new ArrayList<String>();

    List<String> list = locManager.getProviders(true);
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("gps")){
            providers.add("GPS");
        }
        else if(list.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("network")){
            providers.add("Network");
        }
    }

    providers.add("Manual");

    final CharSequence[] items = providers.toArray(new CharSequence[providers.size()-1]);


    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Choose a way of finding your location:");
    dialogBuilder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
           //This is where I'm stuck
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = dialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();}
```

Using a listener will not let me simply return the result through the method, so does anyone know how I could solve this problem?  In a google search people suggested making another function that gets fired upon completion of the dialog, but how would I then return that result to what I am doing in the onCreate method?

Thanks,
Zach

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd split the creation of the UI from the state of the application. I would suggest creating a "null" state for you UI then responding to state change after the user clicks in your dialog.  This pattern is common in C# but not common in Android. Also, if it could be done `onCreate()` must return before the UI is rendered.

Comment: Oh great thanks!  I did not even think about onCreate returning before the UI.  Thanks again!

Comment: if this answers your question you should hit the check box in the top left corner of the answer :)